# Request user again for location permission, when it is already accepted by user ios

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ibeacon, locationmanager

I have an app which is using location service, and some users are already accepted it, but the condition I have here is I want to ask them again now with a condition that if the location is required then only they have to accept it. So, "is there any way to ask user again for the permission when I am giving them a new app update".

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot force the OS prompt for location permission to happen again if it was already accepted.**  One alternative may be to pop a custom dialog, and if the user does not want location to be used anymore, instruct the user to turn it off in iOS app settings, or alternately add logic to simply not use location if the user has made this choice.